# Silverlight isn't sized properly after UR12

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011

We had been using CRM 2011 UR8 but by client request (mostly for the cross-browser compatibility) we have started updating to UR12, and I've run into a problem I can't seem to solve. We use a few custom Silverlight grids, and they all worked perfectly before the update, but now they all load slightly too wide, so that the right edge of the grid is off the edge of the window. I made a simple rectangle to see if the problem was somewhere in our code, but it loads too wide just like the grid. Also, neither the grid and the rectangle resizes when the window is resized.
Here's the xaml for my test rectangle:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="Auto" Height="300">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am testing against an on-premise installation of CRM 2011, using Silverlight 5.1.20125.0, 64-bit. No errors are thrown, either visibly or when using IE's debugging tools. Any help resolving this is appreciated, I'm out of ideas for why this would happen.

Edit: We are applying UR13 to a different environment, and I'm going to test it there, so maybe that'll fix it, but I don't have high hopes since I didn't see anything about it in the [list of resolved issues](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=2791312)

Edit 2: I should add that when debugging the grid (with dummy data) and the rectangle in Visual Studio 2012 they are sized correctly and resize with the window.

Edit 3: UR13 did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can tell, the problem is due to the changes in CSS in UR12. Embedded silverlight now ignores margins, and ends up loading (margin) number of pixels too wide. I'm not entirely sure why it no longer resizes. But in any case, I'm throwing together some javascript hacks to set the width of the grid at load time and adding an onResize event handler to the window that will resize the grid appropriately. Obviously this is a sub-optimal solution, but it should get the job done.